# Verilog: Common bus implementation issue

Tags: verilog

I've been coding a 16-bit RISC microprocessor in Verilog, and I've hit yet another hurdle. After the code writing task was over, I tried to synthesize it. Found a couple of accidental mistakes and I fixed them. Then boom, massive error.

The design comprises of four 16-bit common buses. For some reason, I'm getting a multiple driver error for these buses from the synthesis tool.

The architecture of the computer is inspired by and is almost exactly the same as the Magic-1 by Bill Buzzbee, excluding the Page Table mechanism. Here's Bill's schematics PDF: [Click Here](http://www.homebrewcpu.com/Magic1.pdf). Scroll down to page 7 for the architecture.

The control matrix is responsible for handling when the buses and driven, and I am absolutely sure that there is only one driver for each bus at any given instance. I was wondering whether this could be the problem, since the synthesis tool probably doesn't know this.

Tri-state statements enable writing to a bus, for example:

```
assign io [width-1:0] = (re)?rd_out [width-1:0]:0; // Assign IO Port the value of memory at address add if re is true.
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the io port is bidirectional (inout) and is simply connected to the bus. This piece of code is from the RAM, single port. All other registers other than the RAM have separate input and output ports.

The control matrix updates a 30-bit state every negative edge, for example:

```
state [29:0] <= 30'b100000000010000000000000100000; // Initiate RAM Read, Read ALU, Write PC, Update Instruction Register (ins_reg).
```

The control matrix is rather small, since I only coded one instruction to test out the design before I spent time on coding the rest.

Unfortunately, it's illogical to copy-paste the entire code over here.

I've been pondering over this for quite a few days now, and pointing me over to the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `re` is low, the assign statement should be floating (driving Zs).

```
//                    enable ?   driving          :  floating
assign io [width-1:0] = (re) ? rd_out [width-1:0] : {width{1'bz}};
```

If it is driving any other value then the synthesizer will treat is as a mux and not a tri-state. This is where the conflicting driver message come from.

Comment: I did try this. But maybe I didn't do it properly! I'll try again tomorrow. I wasn't sure whether making it floating was synthesizable. I did discuss with a friend the possibility that it was simply driving everything simultaneously with zeroes.

Comment: Make sure your FPGA supports tri-state. Some do not and some require to instantiate specific modules instead of using the assign statements.

Comment: It's a Spartan 6 TQG144.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Apparently, FPGAs have completely removed internal tristates, so the synthesis tool automatically replaces them with the appropriate logic. It translated!